# Relative Transformations for Bones

Tags: matrix, blender, transformation, skeletal-animation, inverse-kinematics

[image: Bone Transformation]

I'm using Blender to export my armatures in relative coordinates, and I'm trying to get to absolute coordinates in my engine. For the above example, the `childBone`'s tip is an offset of `[-1,0,0]`, which is relative to the forward direction of the `rootBone`, not the global X axis. I understand how matrix multiplication works, but I can't quite seem to get there. Could someone break down the exact steps needed to calculate the absolute coordinates? Here's my attempt:

```
Vector3f rootRoot = new Vector3f(1,1,0);
Vector3f rootTip = new Vector3f(2,1,0);
Vector3f rootTipOffset = Vector3f.sub(rootTip, rootRoot);
float rootLength = rootTipOffset.length();
Quaternion rootRotation = new Quaternion(new Matrix4f().initRotation(rootTipOffset, Vector3f.Y_AXIS));
Matrix4f rootBindPose = new Matrix4f().initTranslation(rootRoot).mult(rootRotation.toRotationMatrix());
//Matrix for the root of the root bone

Matrix4f childOffset = new Matrix4f().initTranslation(rootTipOffset).mult(rootBindPose);

Vector3f childRoot = new Vector3f(0,0,0); //2,1,0
Vector3f childTip = new Vector3f(-1,0,0); //2,2,0
Vector3f childTipOffset = Vector3f.sub(childTip, childRoot);
float childLength = childTipOffset.length();
Quaternion childRotation = new Quaternion(new Matrix4f().initRotation(childTipOffset, childOffset.getRotation().getUp()));
Matrix4f childBindPose = childOffset.mult(new Matrix4f().initTranslation(childRoot).mult(childRotation.toRotationMatrix()));
Matrix4f testMatrix = new Matrix4f().initTranslation(new Vector3f(0,0,childLength)).mult(childOffset);
System.out.println(testMatrix.getTranslation()); //Prints [2, 1, 1]
```